# Querying SQL database with subtypes, displaying it in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have now created a MySQL database for a POS-like system, and i am working with subtypes to put some different types in my database.

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
Prod_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(40),
Barcode INT
);

CREATE TABLE Card(
Prod_id INT,
Price DECIMAL(8, 2),
FOREIGN KEY (Prod_id) REFERENCES Product(Prod_id)
);
CREATE TABLE Weapon(
Prod_id INT,
Caliber_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Prod_id) REFERENCES Product(Prod_id)
);
```

When i scan a barcode, i want to query the database. When a product is found, i want to display all information about it on the screen. I'm using a DataTable in C#, and with every result, i add a DataRow to the DataTable.

So i have 2 questions:
How can i neatly query the database, returning all information i have about a barcode?
How do i display this information in an efficiënt way on my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using only the mentioned tables

Please find the below sql statement which will return all the information as required

```
Select p.Prod_id,p.Name,p.Barcode,c.Price, w.Caliber_id 
from Product p
inner join Card c
on 
(
p.Prod_id  = c.Prod_id 
)
inner join Weapon w
on 
(
p.Prod_id  = w.Prod_id 
) 
where p.Barcode = 'Barcode'
```

if you have some products which does not in card or weapon you can use left outer joins

hope this will help you.

Comment: Well, this wasn't the exact answer, but it definitely gave me a hint in the right direction. When using INNER JOIN, i didn't get any results. If i understand the joins correctly, that's because a product is either a weapon or a card, an never both. 
Using LEFT JOINS gave me pretty much what i wanted. The only thing that i was missing was a column with the type of product, so i added that to Products.

Comment: Hi Marcovannoord don't forget to tick as answered which will divert more answers to your questions